# repr() of dict, but ordered

Tags: python, dictionary, repr

I want a simple way to get the repr() like string of a dict **sorted** by the keys.

```
my_print(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)) -> "{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}"
```

My solution:

```
import collections
print repr(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3).items())))
```

... does not work. Here the wrong output:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

How to implement `my_print()`?

This is not a solution since dicts are not sorted in Python:

```
print dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Comment: What's "wrong" about this output exactly?

Comment: @deceze the output should be **sorted**. repr(dict(..)) is not sorted.

Comment: Because a `dict` has no ordering.

Comment: Your "wrong" output sample looks very sorted to me...

Comment: @deceze: There are two requirements: 1. Sorted 2. Like a dictionary.  OrderedDict is sorted, but is not like a dictionary.  A dictionary is like a dictionary, but not sorted.

Answer (score 4):

The standard dictionary in Python 3.7 is [going to be ordered](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), and in CPython 3.6, `dict` is [ordered due to an implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict), so the following will work with Python 3.7, and probably with your Python 3.6 too:

```
def sorted_dict_repr(d):
    return repr(dict(sorted(d.items())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use JSON.

```
import json
import collections
def my_print(x):
    return json.dumps(x)
```

Result:

```
>>> my_print(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3).items())))
'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'
```

Comment: Then why not `json.dumps(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3), sort_keys=True)`? That way nested dictionaries will be key-sorted as well...

Answer (score 1):

JSON will work only for simple types. Manually it could be done like that:

```
print '{' + ', '.join('%r: %r' % i for i in od.iteritems()) + '}'
```

where `od` is `collections.OrderedDict` object.